# How to recognize images in real time via webcam and show label with accuracy in real time with Keras

Tags: opencv, keras

I am using keras 2 with tf backend and opencv 3,

I want to get image to be recognized from webcam instead of this

```python
test_image = cv2.imread('cat.jpg')"
```

Also i am stacked with printing labels in real time feed. I just do not know how to get images continuously through looping and recognizing. I know it can be done via opencv VideoCapture, just don't know how to do it.

My other information's are

```python
num_classes = 4

labels[0:202] = 0
labels[202:404] = 1
labels[404:606] = 2
labels[606:] = 3

names = ['cats', 'dogs', 'horses', 'humans']
```

I hope you guys help me out. Thanks in advance.

Here is my sample code to test image from path

```python
# Testing a new image
test_image = cv2.imread('cat.jpg')
test_image = cv2.cvtColor(test_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
test_image = cv2.resize(test_image, (128, 128))
test_image = np.array(test_image)
test_image = test_image.astype('float32')
test_image /= 255
print(test_image.shape)

if num_channel == 1:
    if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th':
        test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
        test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
        print(test_image.shape)
    else:
        test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=3)
        test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
        print(test_image.shape)
else:

    if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th':
        test_image = np.rollaxis(test_image, 2, 0)
        test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
        print(test_image.shape)
    else:
        test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
        print(test_image.shape)


# Predicting the test image
print(model.predict(test_image))
print(model.predict_classes(test_image))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you told you can use `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` for webcam input. Flow is like this

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        # Your image is frame. Use this and continue with the prediction
        # Pre Processing of frame
        # model.predict(frame)
```